# How to properly share a partition between Windows Server R2 and Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs-3g

I'm facing the following problem: As the title already says, I want to share a partition between a Windows Server 2012 R2 and an Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS machine.

Some more background information first: Both systems are running simultanously, each one as a VM, on one ESXi host (no dual-boot) - so one host, two running guests. In order to share the storage between those two VMs I created a new drive which is Thick-Provision Eager-Zeroed, set the SCSI to physical, and attached it to both VMs - in general, this works fine as it is shown in both systems.

After accessing the drive from Windows at first, I formatted it as NTFS. I already disabled *hibernate* and *fast reboot* by using the Windows Control Panel and made sure that the registry key (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\HiberbootEnabled`) is set to 0. Additionally, I shut down the system and rebooted to check whether the event ID 13 in case of shutdown and 27 with respect to boot occurs (which is the case).

When trying to mount this drive within my running Ubuntu afterwards (Windows is already up but no user is logged in yet), I receive the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/log/STORAGE: Command-line mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/log/STORAGE"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

As the error message describes, the Windows machine should be fully shutdown. At the moment I think that it is only possible to access the partition from Ubuntu when Windows is not running at the same time.

What I want to achieve is to have both systems up and running where Windows saves some data on the drive and Ubuntu copies it to another location and deletes it afterwards from this shared one. So RO is not sufficient. The VMs are in separated networks and this drive should be the only "interface". When booting Ubuntu first, where Windows is still shut down, and mounting the partition it first seems to be fine. But when I start Windows and use it to create a file on this partition while it's already mounted in Ubuntu, it is not shown in Ubuntu (even after refreshing and closing/opening the file browser) and vice versa.

My question is: Is the approach I am following just completely wrong and if so what should I do instead? Or am I missing a point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state." means windows is maintaining a hibernation file on that partition. And Linux will refuse to mount a filesystem with one on it.

Comment: Even though I disabled *hibernate*? And how can I remove this file? As `mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb2 /media/storage` does not seem to work anymore I tried `ntfsfix /dev/sdb2` as root which mounted the partition without errors, but the inventory does not get updated as described before.

Comment: At several points in your question, you speak as though both Windows and Ubuntu could be (or are) running simultaneously. This is not possible in a traditional dual-boot configuration, which is where you'd share an NTFS volume using Linux NTFS drivers. If you're using virtualization technologies, or if this is a network drive shared by two machines, you should probably be using a network file-sharing tool, like SMB/CIFS/Samba, not trying to share the drive "raw." Please elaborate on the configuration for clarity -- one machine dual-booting, virtualization, two machines, etc.?

Comment: I thought that it was clear that I'm not using a dual-boot setup but running both machines at the same time, but I edited my question. Hope it's clear now what I'm asking.